# How does OneNote handle InkInput on a VirtualSurfaceImagesource

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, direct2d, onenote

According to this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-065) OneNote uses `VirtualSurfaceImageSource` to do its rendering. This allows it to render tiles on demand.

However, the video also indicates that continous input such as inking is best served by using a `SwapChainPanel` using independent input, that allows input events to be handled on a non-UI render thread.

Since OneNote also implements high performance inking, how does it do so? Does it uses a different technique for inking than it does for the rest of the canvas?